# CSS Hover being de-activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I am displaying a page of thumbnails, which if you hover over them, their description is displayed.

for this I am using a span element with CSS

```
.thumb:hover .thumbText {
    display: inline-block ;
}
```

This works fine initially.

But as this needs to work on a touch device and touch does not have hover, I added a button to show all descriptions.

This also works fine, but once I have used the Button Toggle, Description my javascript function has somehow disabled the CSS hover and I can not work out why.

```
var CaptionsOff = true;
function toggleCaptions() {
    if (CaptionsOff) {
        /* Turn Captions ON */
        $('.thumbText').css("display", "inline-block")
        $("#btnCaption").html("Hide Thumb Captions");
        CaptionsOff = false;
    } else {
        /* Turn Captions OFF */
        $('.thumbText').css("display", "none")
        $("#btnCaption").html("Show Thumb Captions");
        CaptionsOff = true;
    }
```

The site is

http://mclportal.net/wcit/June26.html

Comment: Instead of `display` try `visibility`. Use `visibility:hidden;` to hide the text and `visibility:visible;` to show the text.

Comment: What do you mean "disabled the CSS hover"? It works exactly as I would expect it to.

Comment: It does not work after using the button "Show / Hide Thumb Captions" `OSX MountLion with Chrome, Safari and Firefox Browsers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Javascript code adds the CSS to a style attribute on the element. For example:

```
<span style="display:none">Caption</span>
```

Style attributes take priority over CSS files. To change this, modify your CSS script like this:

```
.thumb:hover .thumbText {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

This code means that the display from the CSS is used, rather than from the attribute.

Also, you are missing semicolons.

Hope this helps.

**Alternatives:**

**Toggle a class**

```
$(".buttonCaption").toogleClass("showCap")

.thumb:hover .thumbText, .showCap {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Set the display to nothing**, rather than none. Assumes that the captions are have display:none as default in CSS. Other two solutions are probably better than this.
    $('.thumbText').css("display", "");

Comment: Straightforward when you know how.  That is what this place is for. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Add !important to your class rule. The .css() method adds the style to element's "style" attribute which has higher priority.

```
.thumb:hover .thumbText {
    display: inline-block!important ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting inline style to `$('.thumbText')` in `toggleCaptions()` overrides the stylesheet. Toggle a class instead of setting inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

add this in else with your code::$('.thumbText').removeAttr("style");